# Wix installer input type number

Tags: user-interface, wix, windows-installer, installation

I'm building a custom screen in a Wix installer and I'd like to add a control equivalent to the html5's `<input type="number"/>`

I couldn't find any built-in control type in the documentation nor instructions on how to insert custom controls but I'd expect custom controls to be possible, am I missing something? How could I get a textbox control that only accepts numbers and has up and down arrows on my installer?

Comment: Check out the Wix tutorial here: http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface/new-link-in-the-chain

Comment: That one shows how to add a new custom dialog in the flow, I already have that, I'm asking about a custom control on the new dialog

Comment: The list of controls is defined by Windows Installer - there are no custom ones. Having said that, it sounds like you need something like Control Id="InputNumber" Type="MaskedEdit" Text=the masked edit chars that require number input.  But if you want up/down it sounds like you need a ComboBox or a ListBox that you prefill?

Comment: I received a spec that explicitly requires up and down arrows, but I agree it  doesn't add a lot of value, I guess I'm just gonna try dropping that requirement

Comment: FWIW, a lot of times it doesn't make sense to put configuration data in the installer.  It might make sense to defer the question until application first run resulting in a cleaner installer and a more robust UI in a general purpose programming language.